# Logic behind including / excluding current element in recursive approach

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm studying DP nowadays however I've run into previously some examples like subset sum or as shown in this question coin change problem that their solutions call recursive cases ***both including the current element and excluding the current element***. Yet, I've genuinely difficulty in comprehending what/why it's real reason by doing this approach. I cannot get the underneath logic behind of it. I don't want to memorize or to say *"humm, okay, keep in mind it, there is an approach"* like that styles.

[image]

```
class Util
{
    // Function to find the total number of distinct ways to get
    // change of N from unlimited supply of coins in set S
    public static int count(int[] S, int n, int N)
    {
        // if total is 0, return 1 (solution found)
        if (N == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        // return 0 (solution do not exist) if total become negative or
        // no elements are left
        if (N < 0 || n < 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Case 1. include current coin S[n] in solution and recurse
        // with remaining change (N - S[n]) with same number of coins
        int incl = count(S, n, N - S[n]);

        // Case 2. exclude current coin S[n] from solution and recurse
        // for remaining coins (n - 1)
        int excl = count(S, n - 1, N);

        // return total ways by including or excluding current coin
        return incl + excl;
    }

    // Coin Change Problem
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // n coins of given denominations
        int[] S = { 1, 2, 3 };

        // Total Change required
        int N = 4;

        System.out.print("Total number of ways to get desired change is "
                                + count(S, S.length - 1, N));
    }
}
```

I don't want to skip the parts superficially since recurrence formulas are really play leading role for dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

At each recursion you want to explore both cases:

1. one more coin of type n is used
2. you are done with coin type n and proceed to the next coin type

The remaining task is handled in both cases by a recursive call.

By the way, this solution has nothing to do with dynamic programming.

---

In the common powerset problem, given `(1 2 3)` we are asked to generate `((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) ())`. We can use this *with* and *without* technique to generate the result.

```
+---+         +---------------------------+     +--------------------------------------------+
|   +-with----> ((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1)) |     |                                            |
| 1 |         |                           +-----> ((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) ()) |
|   +-without-> ((2 3) (2) (3) ())        |     |                                            |
+-^-+         +---------------------------+     +--------------------------------------------+
  |
  +-------------------------------------------+
                                              |
+---+           +-------------+   +-----------+--------+
|   +-with------> ((2 3) (2)) |   |                    |
| 2 |           |             +---> ((2 3) (2) (3) ()) |
|   +-without---> ((3) ())    |   |                    |
+-^-+           +-------------+   +--------------------+
  |
  +--------------------------------+
                                   |
+---+           +-----+     +------+--------+
|   +-with------> (3) |     |               |
| 3 |           |     +----->  ((3) ())     |
|   +-without---> ()  |     |               |
+-^-+           +-----+     +---------------+
  |
  |
+-+-+
|() |
|   | <- base case
+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, saying _this solution has nothing to do with dynamic programming_ is not right since the recurrence formula can be/will be used to develop its DP aprroach. Am I wrong, sir?

Comment: Dynamic programming is a quite different approach to solve these kinds of problems. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: @snr please see the diagram I added

Comment: @user633183 thank you so much, it makes more sense now.